# Django South Schema Migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

Suppose I have a DB state that lies in between any schema migration file I have stored. Is there any way I can run a previous migration, while skipping errors like the following?

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "post_postcategory" already exists
```

South runs into this error before it gets to the parts of the migration that don't already exist in the DB. Thanks!

Comment: What about doing `syncdb -all` and then `migrate --fake`? Idk if this would be useful in your case, depends much in your schema changes :/

Comment: I think you have to delete the migration file for that post_postcategory then run something --delete ghost migration, something like that... I forgot. After that you can run the migrate

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run `manage.py migrate --merge`